# Spring Redirect from POST to GET and have back button go back to previous page instead of same page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect

I have a Spring boot application with an html form that calls post mapping in my controller. In that post mapping, it redirects to a get mapping after it's processing. My problem with this now is when the back button of the browser is clicked, it redirects back to the same page the same number as how many times the post was called. So if I do update record 5 times in that page and then click back button , it would take 5 clicks to the back button before it proceeds back to prior page. I'm still new to this, Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

**So I replicated your mentioned scenario-**

So lets assume a page name contact.html

where you have a form in it now when you submit that form it will be handled by your **POST MAPPING** now what have you done is - return statement of your form controller has **REDIRECT TO GET mapping of the SAME PAGE CONTACT.html**

So let's understand the scenario -

1. Every time you hit a submit button the request goes to POST MAPPING in the controller.
2. Every time it redirects you to GET MAPPING and Note, this GET AND POST belong to the same page.

**Now here is the trick-**

3. So  EVERY TIME YOU ARE SUBMITTING you are GETTING a fresh page from the server (check every time your page reloads).
4. As BOTH pages before making POST REQUEST and after POST REQUEST is the same file, you cannot differentiate between pages.

So as you mentioned if you update the record 5 times(let's say record1, record 2, record 3, Record 4, Record 5) then on pressing the back button you will see pages where you updated record 5, then on the next click the page where record 4 was updated and soo on...

**How to visualize the change?**

if you want to visualize then in POST MAPPING  just redirect to another page GET REQUEST ( let say home or index).... then you press back button you will be able to see the difference as these pages are different.

Comment: Hi @Ayush, Thank you for detailing it out , I really appreciate it. Is there a way for me to just stay in that same page where I made the update? the flow is like this menu page then the page where I do updates. I wanted to remain in the update page and go back to menu page when I click back button of the browser.

Comment: your welcome please don't forget to accept the answer and upvote and regarding your requirement, if you want to remain on the same page as usual whatever mapping you have done redirects to  GET request will do the thing but Back button will not take you to home .if your requirement is going for home consederig adding a home/back to home button on top /nav section of page. that is the only way to go directly to home. ALTERNATIVELY   **Stop Caching of that form page(contact.html)** [REFER THIS](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/)

Comment: Hi @Ayush, unfortunately stop caching the page did not work for us.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use spring security for this.

Comment: Hi @tushar,  can you elaborate how Spring security can help? I am using spring security but only for the filters. I'm not sure how I can leverage that for this case.

Comment: ya sure, add this in configure method .headers().defaultsDisabled().cacheControl(); And in your login handler just check user is logged in or not like below     
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String userLogin(Authentication authentication) {
        if(authentication != null) {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        return "userLogin";
    }